# What is the correct way to upload large Base64 encoded files with retrofit?

Tags: java, base64, retrofit2, okhttp

So I'm working with retrofit 2 which uses okhttp underneath. The below code snippet works but I get OOM errors for large files.
I believe this is because I am reading the file to a byte array.

What is the recommended way to work with this?

```
private void appendFileContentsToBody(Attachment attachment, MultipartBody.Builder requestBodyBuilder) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(attachment.getAbsolutePath());
    if(file.exists()){
        RequestBody attachmentPart =  RequestBody.create(null, Base64.getEncoder().encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)));
        requestBodyBuilder.addPart(Headers.of("X-Filename", attachment.getFilename()), attachmentPart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not encode a file into Base64 before sending it, this should be done using stream, which will be done by Retrofit for you. So your code should look like

```
private void appendFileContentsToBody(Attachment attachment, MultipartBody.Builder requestBodyBuilder) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(attachment.getAbsolutePath());
    if(file.exists()){
        RequestBody attachmentPart =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), file);
        requestBodyBuilder.addPart(Headers.of("X-Filename", attachment.getFilename()), attachmentPart);
    }
}
```

where "application/pdf" - is MIME type of the particular file.
That way you will not suffer of OOM ever. However this approach might be implemented on a backend first cuz seems like now your backend implementation made applicable for web-apps only cuz it expects encoded file in a request body.